# which one to chose for mapping an external url ?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

i've a problem and i dont know which one to chose !

i've an external url http://internal.url.com with different path at the end (**/id , /ds-ap, /ds-chat** etc..)

The service will be run by kubernetes and it need to acces to the url with the different path.

my question is.

Do you know if it's possible to map the url with the different path(**/ds-ap, /ds-chat**) by the parameter **externalname** on service ? i didn't found anything about that :(

or

Do i've to setup an Ingress for my service?

i'm a little bit lost :(

Comment: The query is a bit cryptic, would suggest to make it as clear as possible to get a quick and better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define environment variables on for the Containers as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container). Now get the environment variable in the code getting executed in the Container. And based on the value of the environment variable the appropriate external URL can be called. This way the behavior of the Container can be made dynamic. There is no need for Ingress.

Also, [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) can be used to map the value of the environment variable to the URL to be invoked. This will make the Container even more dynamic without hard coding the URL to be invoked in the code.